# Bluetooth spp sniffer

Tags: bluetooth, sniffer, spp

I'm looking for a tool, preferably in Windows, that will allow me to see the byte streams going in and out from the Bluetooth device through SPP. This would be similar to Serial port monitors available for COM and LPT ports.

Answer (score 1):

Since no-one answered your question within 8 months, and I was looking for the same answer too. Here is the answer many people are looking for: there is a tool out there called wireshark that does the trick. Look at all the protocols it can filter out at http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/
See: Bluetooth SPP Packet, Protocol field name: btspp.

As you can see, it will do the trick but you have to learn wireshark first. It's not all childs play after all :-)

Afaik: Wireshark is free to use. Windows and Mac versions both 32-bit and 64-bit available. Linux versions I don't know.

Comment: Not all the protocols Wireshark can dissect (not just filter out; it can't filter out anything it can't dissect) can be *captured* by Wireshark, and not all the types of traffic Wireshark can capture on one operating system can be captured on other OSes.  [The Wireshark Wiki page on capturing Bluetooth traffic](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Bluetooth) does *NOT* speak of any ability to capture Bluetooth traffic on Windows.

Comment: @Guy Harris: not according to this article. http://wiki.wireshark.org/Bluetooth You CAN capture BT traffic on a Windows machine. It's complex, but not impossible.

Comment: It may not be impossible on Windows Mobile (yes, Mobile) with [32feet.NET](http://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Stonestreet%20One%20Bluetopia), and the Stonestreet One Bluetopia Bluetooth stack, but it's impossible with Wireshark alone. (It'd be nice if WinPcap supported it natively, so that Wireshark supported it without any changes, but it currently doesn't.)

Comment: @Guy Harris: aha, I see. I didn't know THAT. Thanks for pointing that out. I don't want to ruin someones party of development enjoyment. Ehm, I mean frustration ;)